# Flutter - How can I show users based on their field values

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a class app and I want to show users if they are from the same class and section based on their fields and values on the Firestore database every student have a field of `grade` and `section` and they have values of the students under it.
and this is how I am getting the students list

```
fetchStudents() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await database
          .collection("users")
          .doc("UGCS")
          .collection("students")
          .orderBy("id", descending: false)
          .get();
      setState(() {
        students = snapshot.docs;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen their is no problem i dont now how to do it